# Dynamic Binding Java

Tags: java, dynamic, binding

In this code, I understand the return value of everything except for query(m). Why does query(m) print one instead of two? Wouldn't it be resolved at runtime that m is of type Winter. And then shouldn't two be printed?

```
public class Season {
    public void weather() {
        System.out.println("cold");
    }
} // end class Season

public class Winter extends Season {
    public void weather() {
        System.out.println("freezing");
    }
} // end class Winter

public class QuizQuestion {

    public static void query(Season arg) {
        System.out.println("one");
    }

    public static void query(Winter arg) {
        System.out.println("two");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Season s = new Season();
        Winter w = new Winter();
        Season m = new Winter();

        s.weather();
        w.weather();
        m.weather();
        query(s);
        query(w);
        query(m);
    } // end main
} // end class QuizQuestion
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  Dynamic binding works for overriding  |  Static binding works for overloading
   (is based on actual instance type)   |      (is based on reference type) 
----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------
class Parent{                           | class Foo{
    public void method(){               |     void handle(Parent p){
        print("parent");                |         print("handling parent");
    }                                   |     }
}                                       |     void handle(Child c){
class Child{                            |         print("handling child");
    public void method(){               |     }
        print("child");                 | }
    }                                   |
}                                       | ...
...                                     | public static void main(String[] args){
public static void main(String[] args){ |     Parent p = new Child();
    Parent p = new Child();             |     Foo f = new Foo();
    p.method();//prints "child"         |     f.handle(p);//handling parent
}                                       | }
```

In other words it determines code based on

```
s.weather(...)
^--------------this part
```

not

```
s.weather(...)
          ^^^--not this part
```

So for

```
Season s = new Season();
Winter w = new Winter();
Season m = new Winter();
```

in

```
s.weather(); //Season prints cold
w.weather(); //Winter prints freezing
m.weather(); //Winter prints freezing
```

but here

```
query(s); //type of s reference (not instance) is Season 
query(w); //type of w reference (not instance) is Winter 
query(m); //type of m reference (not instance) is Season
```

so compiler could only decide to use reference types (since at runtime actual values could be changed) and it invoked methods for arguments of type

```
Season -> one
Winter -> two
Season -> one
```

Comment: Ohhh okay. So in this case we're overloading, so it takes the declared type -- which in this case is Season. But if we were overriding, it would realize at Runtime that the type is Winter. Is that correct?